# Is there a function $f$ from reals to reals such that every non-vertical line intersects $f$ infinitely many times?

Tags: functions, euclidean-geometry

Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for every non-vertical line $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $L$ intersects the graph of $f$ infinitely many times?

Comment: Seems like $\frac{\sin \frac 1x}{x}$ has a pretty good chance of working.

Comment: $f(x) = x^2 \cos x$. For any non-vertical line $y = g(x)$, for sufficiently large $n$, we will have $f(2 n \pi ) > g(2n \pi)$ and $f((2n + 1) \pi) < g((2n + 1) \pi)$.

Comment: @RobertShore $\sin(1/x)/x$ is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Define it any way you'd like at $x=0$.  There was no requirement that $f$ be continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think
$e^x\sin(x)$
will work.

For any line $y=mx+b$,
once $x$ is large enough,
there will be an intersection between
$2k\pi$ and $2(k+1)\pi$
for
$k = \lfloor\frac{x}{2\pi}\rfloor$.